# Drupal 7 - Module with form and view

Tags: 7, views, forms

I'm trying to develop a module that creates a form and a view that displays that page.

In my module I used `hook_menu()` and `hook_form()`.
Also I saw some tutorials [1](https://isovera.com/blog/programmatically-creating-forms-views-drupal-7) & [2](https://drupal.org/node/685432)

What I cannot understand where & how to add my form to the view?

Comment: With view you mean a simple data output and not a view from Views module? What do you mean to add the form to the view? They could beas well separate pages.

Comment: I want to embed my form in view (from views module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used it in that way, but some thoughts:

The second link doesn't seem relevant, as I suppose that you use Views 3.

If you use the approach described in the first link, than you don't need to implement `hook_form()` in your module, instead you need to create a views field handler and there you need to define the methods `views_form()`and `views_form_submit()`, optionally also `views_form_validate()`. You would then "add the form to the view" using the Views UI where you can add the field (the one that you have written a handler for) to the display. That's  how your handler get's called and is responsible for the rendering of the element, which usually renders a value wrapped in some markup, but in your case it would render a form.

The first link explains that all very well. Just go through it again and try to follow it in detail.